# dpkg-buildpackage unrecognized option: `--runstatedir=/run'

Tags: linux, vim, dpkg-buildpackage

I wanted to build vim package for debian from source and I'm getting this error when running command `dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot`

```
   dh_clean
 dpkg-source -b .
dpkg-source: info: using source format '3.0 (quilt)'
dpkg-source: info: building vim using existing ./vim_8.2.5106.orig.tar.gz
dpkg-source: info: using patch list from debian/patches/series
dpkg-source: warning: newly created empty file 'src/auto/config.h' will not be represented in diff
dpkg-source: info: building vim in vim_8.2.5106-1.debian.tar.xz
dpkg-source: info: building vim in vim_8.2.5106-1.dsc
 debian/rules build
dh build
   dh_update_autotools_config
   dh_autoreconf
   dh_auto_configure
        ./configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--runstatedir=/run'
Try `auto/configure --help' for more information
dh_auto_configure: ./configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking returned exit code 1
make: *** [debian/rules:18: build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

If i understand this correctly the problem is in a flag  `` `--runstatedir=/run' `` that is unrecognized. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Did you consider trying the command mentioned in `Try `auto/configure --help' for more information"`?

Comment: @romainl yes, and i haven't found anything helpful

Comment: What did you find, then? Is `--runstatedir` documented? If it is, then you might have found a bug and you should report it.

Answer (score 0):

Before continuing have you installed properly all build dependencies ?

Have a look at : https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control and more especially at the `Build-Depends` section.

In parallel you can also launch the command `dpkg-depcheck -d ./configure` to find some missing packages.

Vim package is regularly updated and last commit was 2w ago so I would be very astonished that it won’t compile.

Have a look at: https://salsa.debian.org/vim-team/vim

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're backporting vim from debian source of a newer distribution to an older distribution.

Then it's caused by debhelper->`dh_auto_configure` adding this parameter. `dh_auto_configure` runs `<source_dir>/configure` with this parameter. `<source_dir>/configure` is generated by `autoconf`, in such case, likely debhelper->`autoreconf`, which calls `autoreconf`->`autoconf` to generate `<source_dir>/configure`. In case the version of `autoconf` is not up-to-date enough, the generated `<source_dir>/configure` lacks `--runstatedir=/run` support, and hence you see this log:

```
   dh_autoreconf
   dh_auto_configure
        ./configure --build=i686-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=\${prefix}/include --mandir=\${prefix}/share/man --infodir=\${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --disable-silent-rules --libdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --libexecdir=\${prefix}/lib/i386-linux-gnu --runstatedir=/run --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking
configure: error: unrecognized option: `--runstatedir=/run'
```

To solve it, you can upgrade your `autoconf` package version, but obviously that's not what you always want to do (you may have to backport a lot of dependencies). So instead, just don't let `dh_auto_configure` pass this argument:
You can see this perl code in `/usr/share/perl5/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/autoconf.pm`:

```
        push @opts, "--runstatedir=/run" if not compat(10);
```

So just modify `debian/compat` in extracted debian source of vim, lower its value to `10`, and build again, now `dh_auto_configure` should never try passing `--runstatedir=/run` when calling `<source_dir>/configure` any more.